# How does printf processes it's arguments when one is pass by reference of another argument

Tags: c, string, pointers, arguments, printf

I found something interesting, but couldn't explain it.
I'm writing a simple routine to reverse a string. This works fine, no complaints.

My issue is in the `printf`. When I print the original string separately, it prints correct, but when I print the original string as the first arg, and the function call to reverse as the second, both show up as reversed.

Output:

> || abcdthelgko ||
>   Orig Str: | okglehtdcba |, Rev Str | okglehtdcba |

Code:

```
char* ReverseStr(char* str, int len)
{
  char *start = &str[0], *end = &str[len-1];
  char temp;

  while(start < end)
  {
    temp = *start;
    *start = *end;
    *end = temp;

    start++;
    end--;
  }
  return str;
}

int main()
{
  char str_unique[] = "abcdthelgko";
  int str_unique_len = sizeof(str_unique)/sizeof(str_unique[0]);

  printf("\n || %s || \n", str_unique);
  printf("Orig Str: | %s |, Rev Str | %s |\n", str_unique, ReverseStr(str_unique, str_unique_len-1));
  return 0;
}
```

*** Modification after feedback : *** 
To test the 2 theories that
 1. Printf processes comments right to left
 2. If a function call is one of the args, that function is called before printf,
I did another sample code to just change the value of a variable passed by reference. What I see is, in variable value, it works correctly:
================== OUTPUT ======================

```
 i = 5, changed i = 2, again i= 2 

 changed i = 2, i= 2 

 i = 5, changed i = 2
```

================== CODE ======================

```
int* change (int* addr);

int main()
{
  int i;
  i=5;
  printf("\n i = %d, changed i = %d, again i= %d \n ", i, *change(&i), i);

  i=5;
  printf("\n changed i = %d, i= %d \n", *change(&i), i);

  i=5;
  printf("\n i = %d, changed i = %d \n", i, *change(&i));
  return 0;
}

int* change (int* addr)
{
  *addr = 2;
  return (addr);
}
```

Comment: Hint: try a third printf with the same as the first one.

Comment: Hi,
To check the theories that, printf processes arguments right to left, or if a function call is an argument to printf, that is processed first before calling the printf function, I wrote another code. 
Instead of str reverse, I tried a simple experiment to change variable value passed by ref...and in that case, I see the original output. i was = 5 and i pass the address of i to a function that writes a 2 in that place: 
`[CODE]:

printf("\n i = %d, changed i = %d \n", i, *change(&i));

[OUTPUT]: 

i = 5, changed i = 2`

Answer (score 6):

Since `ReverseStr` does it's manipulation **in-place** (known as *mutating* the input), the "original" string is no longer available.

When you call a function with another function call as one of its parameters, the inner call is executed first. Consider:

```
printf("%lf", pow(2, 2));
```

The power (`pow`) function is called before `printf`. Same goes in your code, and that mutates the original string, so when `printf` is called it's getting the address of the string that's already reveresed "in both parameters".

One way to resolve this is to allocate a copy of your original string, pass that to `ReverseStr` and then you'd have both versions available at the same time:

```
int main()
{
  char str_unique[] = "abcdthelgko";
  char *str_dup = strdup(str_unique);
  int str_unique_len = sizeof(str_unique)/sizeof(str_unique[0]);

  printf("\n || %s || \n", str_unique);
  printf("Orig Str: | %s |, Rev Str | %s |\n", str_unique,
      ReverseStr(str_dup, str_unique_len - 1));

  free(str_dup); // Don't forget to free the memory allocated by strdup!
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, on your following point: 
When you call a function with another function call as one of its parameters, the inner call is executed first.

That doesn't seem to be true. Instead of str reverse, I tried a simple experiment to change variable value passed by ref...and in that case, I see the original output. i was = 5 and i pass the address of i to a function that writes a 2 in that place:

[ CODE: printf("\n i = %d, changed i = %d \n", i, *change(&i));]                                  [OUTPUT]: i = 5, changed i = 2

Comment: Hi, updated the question with another experiment...it doesn't seem to hold true!

Comment: @SougataChatterjee - Why do you think it doesn't hold true? your example proves it once again. Also it can't be any other way, it would be meaningless for a function to be called after the function that uses it's output has returned. You can also validate this using a debugger if you'd like.

Comment: coz if it was true, in printf when i print i and changed(&i), both should have printed the changed value of 2. but i see it's printing 5 and 2. But for strings....both the string and the func(string) is printing the reversed string. Got the point?

Comment: @SougataChatterjee - All I can say is that it does work this way, and it's just too long to explain in a comment (or even an answer really). My advice to you is to learn from the ground up and as thoroughly as you can about pointers, non pointer types, function calls & stack. I'm sure that once you do you'll have a much deeper understanding of how computers work, how programming works, and this specific issue will be very obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

it runs ReverseStr before printf done, 
string stored in str_unique changed after ReverseStr
then every thing changed:)

Comment: Hi, on your following point: "it runs ReverseStr before printf done,". That doesn't seem to be true. Instead of str reverse, I tried a simple experiment to change variable value passed by ref...and in that case, I see the original output. i was = 5 and i pass the address of i to a function that writes a 2 in that place: 
`___CODE___ ::`
`printf("\n i = %d, changed i = %d \n", i, *change(&i));`
`___OUTPUT___::`
`i = 5, changed i = 2`

Comment: updated the original question with a latest experiment based on your feedback....doesn't seem to hold true to change the value of a number.

Comment: your new experiment output this on vs2015: `i = 2, changed i = 2, again i= 5

changed i = 2, i= 5

i = 2, changed i = 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the passed string in ReverseStr and return it without any modification whilst the passed string will be reversed. (It is usually redundant to return something that is passed by reference but by returning the original copy, your function will prove worthy to return something instead of returning void).

Or allocate memory to hold the reversed string and never mutate the original:

```
char* ReverseStr(char* str, int len) {
    char *reversed = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    int i, j = len - 1;
    for (i = 0; j >= 0; i++) {
        reversed[i] = str[j--];
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

Returning the original but reverse the passed str so you might wanna reverse the print statement in your main

```
char* ReverseStr(char* str, int len) {
    char *start = &str[0], *end = &str[len-1];
    char temp;
    int i;

    char *original = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        original[i] = str[i];
    }

    while (start < end) {
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;

        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return original;
}
```

Comment: 1. not redundant at all to return the address, as exemplified by the question itself. 2. `strdup`.

Comment: I guess you're right but in this case my point was to emphasize that a reference is passed so you'll have access to it in main without returning it. calling the function or simply accessing the variable after the function call will give the same result.

Comment: It's a style / convenience decision, with a minimal performance impact (or non at all with the right optimization), but it's a legitimate pattern

Comment: Hi, my concern was not "How to get the original and get the reversed string?". There are many ways to do that. My point was, when i'm printing the original string first, and then the reverse is getting called, which I agree modifies the string in place....then why is the original string getting reversed. It was more a question on how is printf processing it, than a question of reversing a string!

Comment: Code returns `original` which does _not_ point to a string as the array does not contain a null character.   Suggest insuring `original` points to a string.

Comment: If you agree the original string is modified in the function, how can you expect it to print the old value after calling the mutating function

Answer (score -1):

The function ReverseStr() is modifying the provided string in-situ instead of copying it to a new string.

In C arguments are pushed in the stack from right to left. In you call to printf(), the result returned by ReverseStr() is being pushed first (and at the same time the original string str_unique is being reversed), then the pointer to str_unique is pushed but its contents were reversed by ReversStr().

You should keep the original string unmodified by copying it to a new destination. This new destination can be either allocated in runtime (malloc) inside ReverseStr (don't forget to free it once you have finished using it), or provided by the caller.

Comment: "In C arguments are pushed in the stack from right to left" -- nope -- this may happen in some cases but it is not true in general. Arguments can be passed in any order, and there is no requirement for them to be on the stack.

Comment: You are right that they aren't always are passed in the stack. However, when arguments are passed in registers, the behavior is exactly the same (argument functions executed from right to left) for obvious compatibility reasons.

Comment: It depends on the ABI - some ABIs even use a mixture of register and stack based parameter passing. Also note that *order of evaluation* is not the same as order of passing parameters - there is no requirement that parameters be *evaluated* in any particular order.